# Генерация XLSX-таблицы средствами PHP. Проблема с архивацией

Tags: php, xlsx

В данный момент активно работаю над генерацией XLSX-файлов средствами PHP. С XML-составляющей, вроде, более или менее разобрался, дело осталось за малым, собрать все в zip-архив. Но тут я столкнулся с проблемой следующего плана. Если я делаю архив при помощи PHP, т.е. так...

```
class myzip {

public static function zip($source, $destination) {
    if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
        return false;
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
        return false;
    }

    $source = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, realpath($source));
    $source = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $source);

    if (is_dir($source) === true) {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $file = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $file);
            $file = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $file);

            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..' || empty($file) || $file == DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) {
                continue;
            }
            // Ignore "." and ".." folders
            if (in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) + 1), array('.', '..'))) {
                continue;
            }

            $file = realpath($file);
            $file = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $file);
            $file = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $file);

            if (is_dir($file) === true) {
                $d = str_replace($source . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '', $file);
                if (empty($d)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $zip->addEmptyDir($d);
            } elseif (is_file($file) === true) {
                $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '', $file),
                    file_get_contents($file));
            } else {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    } elseif (is_file($source) === true) {
        $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
    }

    return $zip->close();
}
}

$obj = new myzip;
$obj->zip('folder-to-compress', 'compressed.xlsx');
```

...то результат не открывается в OpenOffice (неправильный формат), а вот, например, с мобильной версией MS Office на смартфоне (Android) таких проблем нет. Кстати, если я создаю архив вручную, тем же WinRAR, то все без проблем открывается и там и там... Чем это можно объяснить, может кто сталкивался?

Читал про такие библиотеки, как PhpSpreadsheet и PHPExcel, но хочется самому во всем разобраться...

Comment: В LibreOffice тоже не открывает :(

Comment: Ну, на прайний случай, можно и `zip` запустить `exec`-ом, если с ним работает.

Comment: Кстати, как я уже говорил, Excel, что мобильный, что десктопный, открывает созданый скриптом архив без проблем, только Open Office вот ругается. Но, что самое интересное, если я распаковываю этот архив WinRAR-ом и потом запаковываю все обратно, то Open Office его окрывает...

Answer (score 0):

Нашел что-то вроде "полурешения". Если я создаю архив напрямую пофайлово, без переборки содержимого архивируемой папки, т.е. так...

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;

if ($zip->open('test.xlsx', ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {

    $zip->addFile('xlsx/_rels/.rels', '_rels/.rels');

    $zip->addFile('xlsx/docProps/app.xml', 'docProps/app.xml');
    $zip->addFile('xlsx/docProps/core.xml', 'docProps/core.xml');

    $zip->addFile('xlsx/xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels', 'xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels');

    $zip->addFile('xlsx/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml', 'xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml');

    $zip->addFile('xlsx/xl/sharedStrings.xml', 'xl/sharedStrings.xml');
    $zip->addFile('xlsx/xl/styles.xml', 'xl/styles.xml');
    $zip->addFile('xlsx/xl/workbook.xml', 'xl/workbook.xml');

    $zip->addFile('xlsx/[Content_Types].xml', '[Content_Types].xml');

    $zip->close();

    echo 'OK';
} else {
    echo 'Error!';
}
```

...то OpenOffice Calc все прекрасно открывает и тем самым создает новые вопросы. Почему так? Может у кого-то есть предположения?